# Selecting from two tables (sales/expenses) with the same column name (total)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried a few things, and so far this is the only thing not throwing an error, but the results wont echo on my page so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales.total) AS sales_total, SUM(expenses.total) AS expenses_total FROM sales,expenses";
```

Everything else is set up perfectly, I've just never had to call multiple tables before.

E.g. of How I am echoing within my HTML:

```
<? echo $row['SUM(sales_total)']; ?>
<? echo $row['SUM(expenses_total)']; ?>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: attached a picture of my nonsense :)[image]

Comment: Can you please give more info/code?

Comment: Try your aliases instead. `<? echo $row['sales_total']; ?>`
`<? echo $row['expenses_total']; ?>`

Comment: @Elias, the results definitely appear where they should now, but the numbers that appear are all wrong. I'm going to try putting 'SUM' back in my echo, and taking 'SUM' out of the query, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: You might want to consult B2K's answer, and figure out how to join them appropriately, or do two separate queries as he suggests.

Comment: That's called a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use two separate queries

otherwise you get  Cartesian product.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I'll never figure out this 'join' business, so extra queries it is!

Answer (score 0):

This is a cartesian join and won't give you the results that you want.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales.total) AS sales_total, SUM(expenses.total) AS expenses_total FROM sales,expenses";
```

You'll need to read up on inner joins to do this properly. Without more details, I can't advise you how to fix that query, other than doing two queries, one for each table. Since you are specifying an AS clause for each field, you'll need to modify your echoes to:

```
<? echo $row['sales_total']; ?>
<? echo $row['expenses_total']; ?>
```

Hope that helps!

UPDATE: revising the query to produce the desired results:

```
$query = "SELECT sales_summary.sales_total,
                 expenses_summary.expenses_total 
          FROM (SELECT SUM(sales.total) AS sales_total 
                  FROM sales) sales_summary, 
               (SELECT SUM(expenses.total) AS expenses_total 
                  FROM expenses) expenses_summary";
```

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what I am doing, or if this is supposed to be in a query at all:

$query = "SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN expenses ON sales.total=expenses.total";

---- that should separate the two identical 'total' columns, now I'm not sure how to call them.

Comment: @Scott That won't work unless your totals are equal. Please do some reading on joins. You need to understand them or you'll end up with incorrect results. I'm editing my response above.